# PHPStorm / Webstorm jquery mobile data-attributes

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, phpstorm

I am a phpstorm user (version 5) and now I'm working on a jquery mobile project. Since jquery mobile uses custom html-data attributes, it would be great, if there is an autocomplete / code completion for the custom data-attributes like "data-icon='add'", "data-role='listview'" and so on.

Is there a plugin or a way to get this autocomplete / code completion done in phpstorm / webstorm IDE?

Comment: Corresponding ticket on Issue Tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2186

Answer (score 4):

Thats easy. This is what you do:

1 - Go to settings

2 - Search for Libraries

3 - Click Add on the side

4 - Add jQuery Mobile.

When adding the mobile version, make sure that you provide the link and add the APIs. Its just like adding another library.

[Here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/04/jquery-offline-doc/) is a walk-through on how to add documentation.

I believe that the api link is this:

```
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That helps me a lot. But is there a possibility to add autocomplete for attribute values as well? I mean, if I type 'data-role="' I get for example 'listview" offered?

Comment: @leftjustified: I am afriad that there is no support for that. I mean, atleast I did not find any, which was a real problem. You might want to request this for future versions of phpStorm.